# Как вывести картинку категории на сайте с Вордпресс (Advanced Custom Fields)?

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

Есть такой дизайн:
[image]
Как видите нужно вывести категории таким образом:

- Название категории
- Картинка категории (сделана с помощью произвольного поля ACF)

Обычная функция wp_list_categories на подходит, так как она выводит обычный список.

Comment: А сами вы что попробовали? Где ваш код?

Comment: Вывести категории циклом, с нужной разметкой, а не функцией